# EawfSite Feature missing. How to remove this?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

After the upgrade to SharePoint 2013 our custom site template will no longer function. I have recreated the site template from the original site, but trying to create a site from this new template still results in the same error.

I have a MS support case open on this one, and they mention that the feature in question is no longer available in 2013 and must be removed - they recommend I contact a SharePoint Developer through the MS partner program to do this. This is ludicrous, I shouldn't have to bring in outside help for this. Can someone help steer me in the right direction for correcting this?

I know the EawfSite Feature is no longer available in 2013, and that I must somehow remove it. Unfortunately I did not create these pages or templates, and I don't know what is using nor how to remove it.

Do I just use SharePoint Designer to delete the thing that uses it? How do I find out exactly what in the site is referencing it?

The full error below -

> This web template requires that certain features be installed, activated, and licensed. >The following problems are blocking application of the template:
>
> Feature Description - EawfSite Feature
>
> Feature Scope - Site collection
>
> Feature ID - 142ae5f3-6796-45c5-b31d-2e62e8868b53
>
> Problem - Not licensed
>
> This template can't be used for this site collection until the issues
>   above are resolved.